# How to do Mapping in Copy Activity with a mix of regular columns and json data?

Tags: azure-data-factory, pipeline

I am having trouble mapping data correctly dynamiccaly with mapping schema in Azure Data Factory

My problem is that I have a mix of regular columns and a column with a Json object
Here is an object from the source:

```
id,environment,catalog,table,data_context,hashcode,operation,updated_at
1351,S2,ss2200,pnt,{"pnt_name":"P000_22"\,"pnt_no":136},DEL,2023-08-16 12:45:58.2470000
```

I have tried to "reach" data_context (which holds the json object) and one of its properties with the following schema defintion:

```
{
        "type": "TabularTranslator",
        "mappings": [
            {
                "source": {
                    "path": "$['data_context'.'pnt_name']"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "name": "pntname",
                    "type": "String"
                }
            }
        "typeConversion": true,
        "typeConversionSettings": {
            "allowDataTruncation": true,
            "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
        }
    }
```

This does not work... I have also tried "path": "$['data_context'][0]['pnt_name']" with no luck.

Hope you are able to help out.

Thanks

*****Update

```
SELECT 
      [table]
      ,JSON_query(data_context) as data_context
      ,[operation]
      ,[updated_at] FROM [BIS_ChangedDataOnEventStage]
where [id] <= 5000
```

the result

```
[
    {
        "table": "pnt",
        "data_context": "{\"pnt_name\":\"P000_KLAUS22\",\"pnt_no\":136,\"}",
        "operation": "DEL",
        "updated_at": "2023-08-17T07:51:42.447"
    }
]
```

The result that I need:

```
[{
    "table": "pnt",
    "data_context": {
        "pnt_name": "P000_KLAUS22",
        "pnt_no": 136
    },
    "operation": "DEL",
    "updated_at": "2023-08-17T07:51:42.447"
}]
```

Comment: Could you please provide your source details?

Comment: @SPT I will, just need to get around to evaluate the proposal

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the issue in my environment I face the same issue:

[image]

I tried below approach to get the required output:
I run the below query in lookup activity

```
SELECT
table_name,
JSON_query(data_context) as data_context
FROM data;
```

I got below output:

[image]

I created array type variable added below expression to the variable

```
@json(replace(replace(replace(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value),'\',''),'"{','{'),'}"','}'))
```

[image]

> **Note:** The above expression will work only for the json in this format.

Set variable Output:

[image]

Added copy activity to the pipeline, selected the source and added below query in query tab to the source:

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(max) = N'@{variables('json')}'
select * from   openjson (@json) 
with
   (
        table_name nvarchar(100),
        pnt_name nvarchar(max) '$.data_context.pnt_name',
        pnt_no int '$.data_context.pnt_no'
   ) as Projects
```

[image]

Added sink to the copy activity after debugging the pipeline it executed successfully. I got below output:

[image]